# Wildcard to obtain list of all directories

Tags: makefile, wildcard, gnu-make

In my Makefile I need to get a list of all directories present in some other directory.

To get a list of all directories in the same folder as my `Makefile` I use:

```
DIRECTORIES = $(wildcard */)

all:
    echo $(DIRECTORIES)
```

which works fine, and gives me the desired list. However if I want to have a list of all directories in another directory using

```
DIRECTORIES = $(wildcard ../Test/*/)

all:
    echo $(DIRECTORIES)
```

I get a list of ALL files (with paths) in that directory, including `.h` and `.cpp` files.

Any suggestions why this happens and how to fix it? Other solutions to obtain the list are also welcome.

Comment: Are you sure wildcarding is a good idea?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't want to add every directory manually, because it is a larger project. If you have an idea how to avoid wildcarding nevertheless, tell me.

Comment: The reason you're seeing this behavior is due to a bug in your version of GLIBC: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10278

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use `sort` and `dir` functions together with `wildcard`:

```
DIRECTORY = $(sort $(dir $(wildcard ../Test/*/)))
```

From GNU make manual:

> $(dir names...)
>   Extracts the directory-part of each file name in names. The directory-part of the file name is everything up through (and including) the last slash in it. If the file name contains no slash, the directory part is the string ‘./’.
>
> $(sort list)
>   Sorts the words of list in lexical order, removing duplicate words. The output is a list of words separated by single spaces.

Also look at the second and the third method in this article: [Automatically Creating a List of Directories](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gnat_ugn_unw/Automatically-Creating-a-List-of-Directories.html)

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complex to me.  I don't know why you need to `sort` for example.  You can use: `$(dir $(wildcard ../Test/*/.))` (note adding the the `.` at the end to ensure that the final character is not a slash) and it will work everywhere.

Comment: @MadScientist, the `sort` ensures that the directories are traversed in alphabetical order. This is useful if you want to be able to tell at a glance how far the build has proceeded, for instance. When I omitted it, I found that on Windows, the directories were traversed in alphabetical order, but on Linux, they weren't.

Comment: @MadScientist Follow your advice and `.` does not get rid of the trailing slash, but it removes the current directory from the list.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your comment.

Answer (score 19):

Try:

```
$(shell find <directory> -maxdepth 1 -type d)
```

which will give you the list of directories inside a given directory without going into subdirectories. You may need to clean that list up since it will include `.` and `./` before every directory listed.

Comment: To get a list without `<directory>` you may use `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`.

Comment: How to eliminate `.` and `./`?

Comment: @Danijel using the `notdir` function on all directories in a `foreach` loop: `$(foreach dir,$(shell find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d),$(notdir $(dir))`

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
$(wildcard ../Test/*/.)
```

This works fine.

Comment: Why does this work? FWIW, it _does_ work but each directory entry will look like `path/to/dir/.`. So `cd` or `make -C` to `.` in some dirent does work, but it looks a little weird if you're printing progress info and you see it in the console, like I had been doing. Couple with `dir` to remove, like `$(dir $(wildcard ../Test/*/.))`

Comment: every directory has two virtual child named `.` and `..` , `.` for current directory, `..` for parent directory, other type of child (regular file, symbolic file, char device etc) don't have child, so the above path filter files out. only directories matched. @sherrellbc